# PHP seems to fail to parse into $_COOKIE correctly

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

I have an incoming HTTP request that looks like this (standard stuff with a couple of cookies being returned from the client):

```
GET /loggedin.php HTTP/1.1
Cookie: name=Server+Side+Name; path=/
Cookie: role=Role+From+DB; path=/
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; Build/JRO03C)
Host: www.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Some PHP which reads:

```
<?php

$body = "\nThe request's _SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] is: " . print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'], true);
$body .= "\nThe request's _COOKIE is: " . print_r($_COOKIE, true);

echo $body;

?>
```

Which results in the following output:

```
The request's _SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] is: name=Server+Side+Name; path=/, role=Role+From+DB; path=/

The request's _COOKIE is: Array
(
   [name] => Server Side Name
   [path] => /, role=Role From DB
)
```

Note the second entry in `$_COOKIE` is "path" not "role" and its value is incorrect.

It certainly looks like the cookies which appear correctly (albeit concatenated) in `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']` are being parsed incorrectly to populate `$_COOKIE` but I can't believe that's the case. I control all of the elements so what should I be doing differently to get the correct values into `$_COOKIE`?

If it matters this is on PHP 5.3.27 on an EC2 Amazon Linux instance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it's easy to confuse the `Set-Cookie` and `Cookie` headers.

Only the `Set-Cookie` header has options like `path` and `expires`.  The `Cookie` header does not because those options are consumed by the client when deciding whether to send the cookie or not.

The reason my request contains these options on the `Cookie` header is that I'm trying to work around an issue with certain Android HTTP implementations and got the headers confused in my code logic.